# How can I enable checkbox 'deploy' in my solution configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, jenkins

I am using Visual Studio 2013. My solution contains multiple projects. there is one MVC4-project. When I build my solution via MSBuild on Jenkins I want to deploy the MVC4-project:

[image: Deploy MVC4]

The chekbox is disabled. How can I enable this checkbox?

Comment: Not an answer to this question but you can pass `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` to MSBuild to deploy it from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on answer to the same question https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bd461d5-79ce-4cd1-b4f4-1cc55e2abc5b/what-we-need-to-have-the-deploy-checkbox-in-configuration-manager-enable-?forum=visualstudiogeneral - it seems that Deploy have nothing to do with publishing, but is about some projects, which Visual Studion treats as deployable.
To deploy you project via Jenkins, you can pass following parameters to build:

- /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=computername or path to msdeploy handler on remote computer (https://some_site:8172/msdepoy.axd
- /p:UserName=username for deployment (either administrator or must be allowed at IIS level for site)
- /p:Password=password for user above
- /p:AuthType=Basic
- /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True (if you are using self-signed certificate for msdeploy)
- /p:DeployIisAppPath=iis site name
- /p:DeployOnBuild=True
- /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish